# How can i install vue cli?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I come here to solve this problem: I have installed `node (Ver. 12.13.1)` in my computer, then I use `node -v` to see if `node` are well installed, and yes, it is.

Later, I use `npm install @vue/cli`, it installs the framework, but when a do a `vue --version` throws me a error.

I have tried in the terminal of visual studio code and throws me the error too. I tried uninstall and install node, and do the before stuff again, but its not working, the error remains

What could I do? Why is this happening?

***Error in english:***

```
Cannot load file C:\Users\halva\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1. 
The file C:\Users\halva\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 is not digitally signed.
You cannot run this script on the current system. 
For more information about the execution of scripts and execution policy settings, 
see about_Execution_Policies at https: /go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID = 135170
```

Photos of the code: 
[PS Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjkaF.png) and
[Visual Studio Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mn6m.png)

Comment: This looks like an issue with `PowerShell`... Try to run this first (if you would have read the error message, and gone [to the link they provide](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170), it gives you all the answers you are looking for) `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can confirm this is a powershell issue:

Please read this github issue on the matter: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3424

People have suggested getting the same issue with vue-cli installed globally.

**Solution:** delete the erroring file: File C:\Users\halva\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1.

Sidenote:
What I suggest is to not use powershell, and use something like gitbash: https://gitforwindows.org/ (but this is entirely an opinion)

Answer (score 0):

this command help to get rid off error message and execute the command, I am sharing here for help, looks like you should be sure whatever libraries you are using they are safe for your computer.

```
>Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Source https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3424

Answer (score -1):

You should install vue-cli globally

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```